Writing Pandas dataframe to MS SQL Server is too slow even with fast parameter options
I've been trying to insert a relatively small Pandas Dataframe (~200K records) to Azure Synapse. For this purpose I've tried a bunch of different methods and approaches, revolving around PYODBC and SQLAlchemy APIs.
However, no matter the approach, I notice that the write speed of my dataframe to SQL Server is only ~ 10 records/second. This is obviously not viable, unexpected, but most of all, its cause is a mystery to me.
I've spent a good amount of time searching the web for resources on how to increase the write speed, and found a bunch of people raising similar issues and asking for advice.
I'm aware of the .fast_executemany option when creating the SQLAlchemy.engine which supposedly speeds up the write speed considerably, but as you can see, even with it, the results are not desirable.
I've also tried using executemany on a cursor, but the results have the exact same performance.
Another attempt I made was with turbodbc, which also yielded the same performance.
My dataframe has 11 columns, all being float except one.
From what I've read in documentation, fast_executemany option is supposed to attempt to fit the entire dataframe in-memory, however during the operation, I notice that my computer's Memory consumption doesn't change.
I'm truly at a loss here. Any ideas on the cause of this, and some remedy?
Here's my code:
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL, create_engine

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
                      'Server=SERVERNAME;'
                      'Database=DATABASENAME;'
                      'MARS_Connection=yes;'
                      'UID=USER;'
                      'PWD=PASS;')

connstring = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;UID=USER;PWD=PASS;"

conurl = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect":connstring,'autocommit':'True'})

dbEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conurl, fast_executemany=True)

#for the sake of this example I only have 2 columns
d = {'userid': ['21005395', '20101499'], 'col1': [0.1, 0.25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Even when only inserting 1K rows, the time to complete is ~130secs
df.head(1000).to_sql(
                    name = 'databaseTable'
                    , con = dbEngine
                    , schema = 'schema'
                    , method = None
                    , index = False
                    , chunksize = 500
                    , dtype = {
                        'userid' : sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(10)
                    , if_exists='replace')

environment, using Anaconda 2.6.3:
Python: 3.10.14 
pyodbc: 5.1.0 
pandas: 2.2.3 
sqlalchemy: 2.0.34

Do you notice any difference in performance between fast_executemany=True and fast_executemany=False ?

You might also try this to_sql() method to see if it helps any.

MARS is a technology that allows multiple active result sets to be multiplexed over a single database connection, allowing concurrent SELECT and BULK INSERT operations but queueing DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE operations. Have you tried turning it off to see if it makes a difference?

@GordThompson no difference between True and False. I have also tried to use the to_sql custom function that you’ve linked (saw it yesterday in a Github thread), but nothing changes unfortunately.

@AlwaysLearning frankly no, I haven’t tried turning it off, however in the snippet that I’ve added, you can see that the conn variable is unused, therefore I wouldn’t anticipate it to have any impact.

True, but we can only guess about the nature of the code you haven't shown us, and the code you have shown us has syntax errors (probably because you truncated the dtype parameter to to_sql().

Is there someone in your organization who could offer some insight on how Azure might be throttling your write requests? I won't pretend to understand the majority of what's written here except to note that write limits appear to be way lower than read limits.

I would suggest using SQL Server's Extended Events, or SQL Profiler, to monitor the batches that your Python code is actually submitting. Likely it's still using RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) to insert one row for each INSERT operation. Other factors could be table triggers and the latency between your client and the targeted SQL Server instance (TDS, the client-server protocol used, was designed for LAN connections 30+ years ago and performs horribly as latency increases over the open internet).

@GordThompson I've given another go to the alternate to_sql() method that you suggested. When I run it, I get the following error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]104220;Cannot find data type 'ntext'. (100000) (SQLExecDirectW)")
How is this possible, given that there's code which is supposed to replace any "TEXT" and "NTEXT" to NVARCHAR(MAX)?
My dataframe's data types after running df.dtypes are : UserID: object and the rest are float64.

@GordThompson I see a relevant Github issue which concludes that the addition of LongAsMax=yes in the connection string is supposed to resolve it. However, even after adding this parameter, the error remains.

Your code x 1000 rows minus MARS connection + Trusted_Connection takes like 0 seconds to run on my local weak laptop's sql server. So something is very wrong somewhere

LongAsMax=yes is a feature of ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server. AFAIK it has not been backported to 17.

@siggemannen Yeah, something's definitely very wrong, but I know neither what nor where.

Your 10 records / second seem to be very low to me. I guess it might be worth it to investigate where the bottleneck is. However, I found that if you need maximum insert performance, you should write your data to csv and then use COPY FROM or in your case COPY INTO to insert that csv into the table. Or even use parquet, but I have not done that.
You can see here how that schema works with Postgresqls psycopg2, but it will be similar with pyodbc.

Copy is for postgresql, OP is using SQL Server

Yes, that is why I have clarified that for SQL Server COPY INTO has to be used.

@McToel If I used your approach, than I'd have to save my dataframe into a .csv file, and then place this file somewhere in Blob Storage, where Synapse would be able to "see". Do I understand correctly?

Well, in theory you can save your csv to a StringIO so it stays in memory, and then send it together with an INSERT INTO command to your database. However, pyodbc seems to not support this. I have found a gist showing how to accomplish it using JSON here. CSV should work similar, but in the end I have not clue, I can just tell you then this schema is to my experience always the fastest.
